# Cambiar dinámicamente imagenes cada x segundos con settimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

Deseo cambiar automaticamente cada x segundos la imagen X por la imagen Y, así sucesivamente usando el método setTimeOut o interval.

**Código:**

```
   $("#cambiar_imagenes_x_segundos").click(function() {
        var img = new Image();

        var src1 = 'isco.png';
        var src2 = "torres.png";
        //Si el contenido (.html()) del ID imagen esta vacio, NO hay foto.
        if ($('#imagen').html().trim() == "") { //.trim() para quitar los espacios.
            img.src = src1; //Cargamos la imagen de Isco (imagen1) al atributo "img.src".
            $('#imagen').append(img); //Añadimos la imagen "img" al id "#imagen".
            $(this).val("Cambiando imagen automaticamente..."); //Cambiamos de nombre al boton llamandolo "Cambiar foto".
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);
        } else {
            //Si hay foto...
            if ($('#imagen>img').attr("src") == src1) {
                $('#imagen>img').attr("src", src2);
            } else {
                $('#imagen>img').attr("src", src1);
            }
        }
    });
```

**¿Cómo se podría añadir a este código un setInterval o setTimeOut para que cada X segundos cambie de imagen?** Para no tener que pulsar el botón para modificar la imagen.

Comment: no veo error, problema, o pregunta alguna :P

Comment: ¿Cómo se podría añadir el settimeout para que varíe cada x segundos?

Answer (score 3):

Deberías encapsular tu comportamiento en una funcion y luego con el click en #cambiar_imagenes_x_segundos , iniciar el timeout:

```
$("#cambiar_imagenes_x_segundos").click(function() 
{
     setTimeout(myfunction, 3000); //3 seg
});

funciton myfunction ()
{
   var img = new Image();

        var src1 = 'isco.png';
        var src2 = "torres.png";
        //Si el contenido (.html()) del ID imagen esta vacio, NO hay foto.
        if ($('#imagen').html().trim() == "") { //.trim() para quitar los espacios.
            img.src = src1; //Cargamos la imagen de Isco (imagen1) al atributo "img.src".
            $('#imagen').append(img); //Añadimos la imagen "img" al id "#imagen".
            $(this).val("Cambiando imagen automaticamente..."); //Cambiamos de nombre al boton llamandolo "Cambiar foto".
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);
        } else {
            //Si hay foto...
            if ($('#imagen>img').attr("src") == src1) {
                $('#imagen>img').attr("src", src2);
            } else {
                $('#imagen>img').attr("src", src1);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: te da error ? o que ?